# Logging with heroku (rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku

A gem used by an application is generating logs to /var/log/project_name.

Locally all looks fine, just had to create the folder and add some permissions to it.

When I try to create the same folder on heroku I get this:

```
heroku run bash
~ $ mkdir /var/log/project_name
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/log/project_name’: Read-only file system
```

I can change the dir to log to the same folder where the code is, but what is the correct way to save some log files with heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like heroku doesn't allow to write to file system as they are working with dynos:

> By default Rails writes its logs to a file, which is convenient because you only have one log file to tail. When you start scaling your app to multiple machines or dynos, it becomes much harder to find a single request or failure as they're spread across multiple files. Storing logs on disk can also take down a server if the hard drive fills up. Because of these limitations, every Rails core member we talked to uses a custom logger to replace Rails' default functionality. By using the rails_stdout_logging gem with Heroku, we set the logger for you.
>   https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging

The best option for me is to stream to STDOUT and to use one of heroku logging addons to archive and etc..